# basic anova for all columns

Tags: r, anova

I would like to perform an anova for all the columns in my data set.
I tried this:

```
aov.ex2 <- aov(base~1*2*3,data=data1) 
summary(aov.ex2)
```

results in

```
8   1   4.83E+08    482880306   29.802  7.90E-08    ***
2   1   7.34E+07    73427001    4.532   0.03381 *
7   1   5.39E+07    53881269    3.325   0.068875    .
5   1   1.53E+07    15340263    0.947   0.331062    
0   1   1.39E+07    13937464    0.86    0.354179    
3   1   7.05E+06    7053679 0.435   0.509716    
6   1   5.99E+06    5990139 0.37    0.543473    
3   1   1.53E+06    1526782 0.094   0.759008    
1   1   5.26E+05    526334  0.032   0.85705
```

but the results do not match:

```
aov.ex2 <- aov(base~1,data=data1) 
summary(aov.ex2)

aov.ex2 <- aov(base~2,data=data1) 
summary(aov.ex2)

aov.ex2 <- aov(base~3,data=data1) 
summary(aov.ex2)
```

results in:

```
0   1   1.39E+07    13937464    0.536   0.465           
Residuals   709 1.85E+10    26021810                    
1   1   9.70E+06    9701265 0.373   0.542           
Residuals   709 1.85E+10    26027785                    
2   1   1.57E+07    15712139    0.604   0.437           
Residuals   709 1.85E+10    26019307                    



aov.ex2 <- aov(base~col1+col2+col3,data=data1)
```

results in

```
0        1 1.394e+07  13937464   0.549  0.4591    
1            1 5.263e+05    526334   0.021  0.8856    
2           1 7.343e+07  73427001   2.890  0.0896 .  
3           1 1.527e+06   1526782   0.060  0.8064    
4          1 7.054e+06   7053679   0.278  0.5984    
5             1 1.534e+07  15340263   0.604  0.4374    
6            1 5.990e+06   5990139   0.236  0.6274    
7             1 5.388e+07  53881269   2.121  0.1457    
8            1 4.829e+08 482880306  19.007 1.5e-05 ***
Residuals   701 1.781e+10  25404903
```

Could someone explain the difference to me?
I got the code from this webpage:
http://personality-project.org/r/r.anova.html

I am trying to test the my ability to characterize base using the variables in col 1-n
I thought Anova gave a significance to the variable ability to correlate with the base.
If I can find the significance of each variable working together that would be great too but I don't fully understand the output at the moment.

Here is some sample data from the file
It is space delimited to be read in with read.table.

```
data1 <- read.table(file=args[1], sep='\t', header=T, row.names=1)
    base    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
707 1   1389    430 493.6   0.3096  0.3554  525.47  0.3783  170.29  0.1226
708 4   1392    440 472.8   0.3161  0.3397  669.32  0.4808  197.07  0.1416
709 9   1403    437 487.4   0.3115  0.3474  581.1   0.4142  174.45  0.1243
710 49  1469    476 658.1   0.324   0.448   378.88  0.2579  123.59  0.0841
711 4   1428    435 513.5   0.3046  0.3596  503.33  0.3525  151.95  0.1064
```

Comment: You need to either include a link to the data or explain in much greater detail what you mean by "results do not match". Obviously these are different models, but you have given us no background about even the type of variables in col1, col2, and col3.

Comment: @DWin thanks I'll post some sample results I cant post data though

Comment: paste the output of `dput(data1)`. If the data is secret, try something like `dput(sapply(data1, jitter))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that the first example is a test of all main effects, two-way, and three-way interactions of a three factor ANOVA whereas the second through fourth examples are tests of a single factor.

Specifically, the first test will answer all of the following:

1. Main effects:

   - is there an effect of col1 on base?
   - is there an effect of col2 on base?
   - is there an effect of col3 on base?
2. Two-way interactions:

   - does the effect of col1 on base depend on the level of col2?
   - does the effect of col2 on base depend on the level of col3?
   - does the effect of col1 on base depend on the level of col3?
3. Three-way interaction:

   - if you don't know how to interpret this, it should not be in the model

The second through fourth tests will answer the three questions under main effects, but it is probably more appropriate to test these at the same time:

```
aov.ex2 <- aov(base~col1 + col2 + col3, data = data1)
```

Comment: in my data i'm not measuring causality not effect am I using the wrong test? I saw the F value for 1 way anova and assumed that it was a significance like coloration

Comment: @caseyr547 it is not clear what you are asking, but probably. You should re-write your question with some example data and the hypothesis that you are interested in testing

Comment: Thank you I update it asap with the jitter like you suggested

Comment: I posted some sample data and updated the question with my goal. I think you have the answer I just dont understand your response yet.:)

Answer (score 2):

Edit after data and input statement added:

```
data1 <- read.table(text="   base    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
 707 1   1389    430 493.6   0.3096  0.3554  525.47  0.3783  170.29  0.1226
 708 4   1392    440 472.8   0.3161  0.3397  669.32  0.4808  197.07  0.1416
 709 9   1403    437 487.4   0.3115  0.3474  581.1   0.4142  174.45  0.1243
 710 49  1469    476 658.1   0.324   0.448   378.88  0.2579  123.59  0.0841
 711 4   1428    435 513.5   0.3046  0.3596  503.33  0.3525  151.95  0.1064
 ",  header=T, row.names=1)
# This will give a typical ANOVA
 aov(base~. , data=data1[ , 1:4] )
summary(aov(base~. , data=data1[ , 1:4] ))
```

The usual way to add all other variables with an implicit formula connector of "+" is to just add a dot "."

You can run an interaction model but you will need to know what you are doing  in order to make any sense of it. The column names got automagically prepended with "X" since R does not like leading digits in its column names.

```
summary(aov(base~X0*X1*X2 , data=data1[ , 1:4] ))
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
X0           1 1292.1  1292.1
X1           1  287.9   287.9
X2           1   15.3    15.3
X0:X1        1   21.9    21.9
```

Notice that there are not as many levels in the interaction model. You only had 5 rows of data and that would only support estimating 4 parameters.

Comment: thanks for clueing me in I will post space delmited data sorry i'm so new at this R isnt my favorite language :)

Comment: We still cannot tell what sort of object that data is from. Offering console print output does not provide the needed details. It does not look like a dataframe, since those column headers do not begin with characters. You had a matrix before. Have you fixed that potential error?

Comment: I'm very sorry I don't know R very well which command would you like to see output from?